# How can I uninstall outlook app from windows 10 completely?

Tags: uninstall, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to offload the data space of ms outlook from my hard drive as it took a large amount. Can it be uninstalled?

Comment: Do you want to keep the other Office apps (Word, Excel etc)?  If you want to keep them do you actually want to uninstall Outlook or just delete the files containing your emails and leave the program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the size of Outlook data files, we can archive mailbox to PST files and then move PST files to another drive. Reference:[Archive Items Manually](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6)

If you want to uninstall Outlook individually from Office 365, we can do this via Control Pane. Reference:[How to Uninstall Outlook from an Office Installation](https://www.slipstick.com/tutorial/how-to-uninstall-outlook-from-an-office-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html), which is free for a 30 day trial (and well worth purchasing).

Nothing beats it for a complete uninstall . It will run a normal uninstall, then scan the registry for left over entries, and your hard drive for left over directories and files and offer you the option to remove them.

Comment: No reason for the downvote? Look at my reputation on this site. I tried many, many, many uninstallers, mostly free, but also 30 day trials of commercial products, until I decided to pay for this. I have nit regretted it. I don't mind a downvote, but we are here to try yo help, and just downvoting without a reason does not help others who read this question. I stand by my answer.